# Python sqllite3 doesn't return list

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have a list of values (only one value for now)

```
testList = ["value1"] #or is this an array in python??
```

and I would like to get this list from database

so I tried like this (assuming I have myTerribleTable in my DB and it has one atribute named "myAtribute" which has values "value1"

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
```

so I execute the query: `print(conn.execute(SELECT myAtribute FROM myTerribleTable).fetchall())`

so I expect to get back `['value1']`

but I get `[('value1',)]` this is not a list, it looks like a tuple even prepending evething with list like that `print(list(conn.execute(SELECT myAtribute FROM myTerribleTable).fetchall()))` doesn't work I still get `[('value1',)]` instead of desired `['value1']`

not sure what is happening
Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: "fetchall" always returns a list of tuples (here the tuple only has one item). You need a for-loop or list comprehension to extract the tuple items into a new list.

Comment: Each row can contain one or more columns. So `fetchall` returns a list of sequences.

Comment: And I'm fairly sure that it's not just a tuple, its `sqlite3.Row` row object and it only mimics tuple. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects

Comment: but this seems such a waste of resources that you need a for loop to convert a tuple to a list can't I make fetchall return list instead?

Comment: Can you tell me how do you return a sql row containing multiple columns with column names in a simple list? @TitovkaJeKapa

Comment: well of course you can't but its only one column in this case if I talk with SQL direcly it will always (in this case) return one column with multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
rows = conn.execute("SELECT myAttribute FROM myTerribleTable").fetchall()
output = List()
for row in rows:
   output.append(row.["myAttribute"])
```

With this loop you could convert the row objects into a list of values

Comment: well if this is the least wastefull aproach then I gues I will have to live with it :), wish there would be an extension method for featchall() that would do the loop for me :)

Comment: Well it's the least wasteful way. You could also just use the the Row objects directly. That way you wouldn't need to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list(conn.execute(SELECT myAtribute FROM myTerribleTable).fetchall()[0]))
```

How about this?

Comment: This will fail if the list has more than one tuple.

Comment: well this works but if list has more than 1 element then it only returns the first one :)